# Download file or Open if file type is PDF

Tags: php, pdf, file-io, download

I have this code right here:

```
if(isset($_POST['file_id'])){
    $file_id = $_POST['file_id'];
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT `IdDocumento`,`nome_ficheiro`,`caminho_ficheiro`
            FROM  `documento` 
            WHERE `IdDocumento` = $file_id");           
    $result = $query->fetch_object();
    $caminho = $result->caminho_ficheiro;
    $nome = $result->nome_ficheiro;
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nome.'"');
    readfile($caminho);
    exit();         
}
```

which download the file from one page. It works fine for downloads. But I want to add an if to that code..
Something like:

```
    if (file is a PDF) {
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    }else{
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nome.'"');
        readfile($caminho);
        exit();
}
```

so if the file is a PDF file it opens the file instead of downloading it.
How do I do this? I searched but I couldn't find how to check the file type.

EDIT (RIGHT SOLUTION):

```
    if(isset($_POST['file_id'])){
    $query = "SELECT `IdDocumento`,`nome_ficheiro`,`caminho_ficheiro`,  `tamanho_ficheiro`
            FROM  `documento` 
            WHERE `IdDocumento` = ?";
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $file_id);
        $file_id = $_POST['file_id'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($IdDocumento, $nome_ficheiro, $caminho_ficheiro, $tamanho_ficheiro);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if (strtolower(pathinfo($nome_ficheiro, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'pdf') {
                header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$nome_ficheiro.'"');
                readfile($caminho_ficheiro);   
            }else{
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nome_ficheiro.'"');
                readfile($caminho_ficheiro);
            }
            exit(); 
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }else{
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }   
}else{
    echo"Download do ficheiro falhou";
}
```

Comment: There is an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) in this code. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if (file is a PDF) {` condition can be implemented in multiple ways; the easier may be to just consider that the file is PDF if it has a `pdf` extension:

```
if (strtolower(pathinfo($nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'pdf') {
```

---

BTW, there is an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) in this code. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you, got it working :)

Can you tell me if I'm using the prepared statements correctly? I edited the question with the prepared statement.